# Maximal Solution to Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the differential equation $$\dot x = x(1-x), x(0)= \frac 12$$

Decide if the solution exists for all $t \ge 0$ or only on a finite time interval $0 \le t \lt T$.

By the theorem, for the maximal solution either
$T = \infty $,
${T \lt \infty }$ but $\lim_{t \to T} DNE$,
or ${T \lt \infty }$ and $\lim_{t \to T}$ exists.

I did a problem similar to this which was $$\dot x = \cos x + \sin t, x(0)=0$$ which I found to be $T= \infty$ because $\dot x$ is bounded so the limit exists by theorem, but this problem is throwing me off.

My attempt: I don't believe I'm supposed to actually solve the D.E., so without doing that, there is no restriction on the domain of my $\dot x$ just $[t_0, \infty)$, so then it's not bounded, so then would $T=\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $x=0$ and $x=1$ are equilibrium points. Hence, any solution starting on $(0,1)$ will be global, that is, it will be defined for all $t\in\mathbb R$. This is so because it cannot pass through $0$ or $1$. Hence, it is bounded, which implies that the maximal interval is $\mathbb R$.